# Не могу разобраться почему тест параллельно не запускается

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, junit, parallel

Запускаю в терминале ("mvn clean test -Dtest=TestFirst")
   В конфигурации плагина указал количество потоков, но запускается только один поток.

```
public class TestFirst {
    public static WebDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        File file = new File("D:/ieDriver/IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void nunzioweb(){
        webDriver.get("https://nunzioweb.com/iframes-example.htm");

        webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        webDriver.switchTo().frame(0);

        webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/button")).click();
        System.out.println("Test passed");
    }

    @After
    public void close(){
        webDriver.quit();
    } }


Pom:



 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Result:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вы хотели запускать в несколько потоков именно один конкретный тестовый метод, а не делить несколько разных тестов по потокам посредством surefire. Если это так, то вам необходимо это явно указать, например, в аннотациях TestNG: `@Test(threadPoolSize = 30, invocationCount = 100)`, но, возможно, я что-то упускаю, и в surefire, все же, можно сделать так, как хотите вы.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал. Но не параллельно запускает, создает несколько потоков и запускает по очереди, то бишь пока браузер не исполнит тест скрипт, остальные потоки ждут. Хотелось бы один тест запустить одновременно.